# Installed package has out-of-date header files

Tags: npm, node-addon-api

The node-addon-api package is installed and I have been compiling using those header files just fine. But I went to take advantage of a feature and my addon would not compile; the symbol was missing from the headers.  After comparing to the header file in their github repository, it was clear that what's installed is not what's current.

The file dates of everything (on a Windows install) is shown as 26-Oct-1985, but I don't know if that's npm just not getting the date right when it writes the file out, or what.

What do I need to do to get the current version in place?  npm reports that v.3.0.2 is installed, but even after deleting the directory and letting npm fetch it again, the files are out-of-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was strange; I finally realized that the reason the file kept looking like it was out of date was because the text editor I had it loaded in was not reloading when the file got rewritten by npm -- probably because of the file's datestamp never changing from 26-Oct-85.  I discovered this after taking a diff between the installed file and the one in a clone of the package's repo: no difference.